# Getting output of 9v DC from 5v DC?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

So I've three relays connected in parallel. Each of them gets triggerd with 9v and I've a 5v source. Can I trigger all the relays with 5v by connecting  some kind of  additional electrical part, like capacitor or something? Btw they all should be triggered always be default (continuous flow should be present).

Also a 5v relay is not available where live, so I've to manage with the same relays. [image: actually relays are of 12v but it can be triggered by 9v]

Comment: You could use a boost converter, but these are (although easy to source) are harder to come by than 5V relays. So if finding a 5V relay is a problem, finding a boost converter module probably will as well.

Comment: Google "step up converter". You need a circuit consisting of a controller ic, a few resistors and capacitors, and an inductor. I cannot give more details because I am on mobile now. But I am sure other users can.

Comment: I have seen this done without a boost converter by using a capacitor and a couple of transistors to temporarily supply twice your available rail voltage. I will try to reconstruct the circuit later if nobody has answered in the meantime.

Comment: Better off using 12V relays for cars and PC power supply with a transistor or mechanical switch.  ( you have old cars and old PC's there right? ;)

Comment: As others have said, you're after 5V-to-12V for the 12V relays you show. Have a look/search for 'DC-DC converter' modules, you can get all-in-one ready-to-use enclosed modules that are nice and small. Unfortunately, they're not particularly cheap and at that point, 5V relays would cost you less.

Comment: @TonyM On the other hand, you only need 1 boost converter instead of three relays.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, yes you're right and I'm wrong - just looked at typical prices, my estimates were miles off :-)

Comment: I'll check for converter. Thanks a lot all of you.

Answer (score 3):

Those relays say 12v on them, not 9v.

Even if they do pull in at 9v, you're on the edge. An increase in temperature would increase their resistance and therefore lower the current.

To take up replete's suggestion, this is how you might attempt to provide a higher voltage to pull the relays in, and then sustain with a lower voltage. This is usually possible as a closed relay has a better magnetic path than an open relay, so the drop out current is much lower than the pull in current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7cMXC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 charge C1 to full rail potential while Q1 is off. They need to be small enough to do this in the time you have available, and large enough not to lose too much charge during the pull in sequence.

When you want the relay to pull in, drive both transistors on. Q1 pulls the bottom of C1 up to rail, meaning nearly 2x rail appears through D1 at the relay. C1 must be large enough to power the relay coil during pull in, while not dropping to below the pull in voltage.

Once C1 has discharged, the relay is sustained by nearly the rail voltage through D2. These would be schottky diodes for minimum voltage drop. Q1 can be turned off at this point, or left on. C1 doesn't recharge until Q1 is turned off.

To release the relay, turn off Q2.

Comment: I actually didn't understand most of the theoretical part but thanks for the diagram, I'll try to implement it.

Comment: Unless you understand the theoretical part, you won't be able to choose values for what I've drawn, or add the bits I've left out.